# Is it possible access my home network with a VPN if it is using a cellular network?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, cellular-internet

My home network uses a cellular internet connection. As such, it doesn't have a static nor a publically reachable dynamic IP, so services like dynDNS are not an option. I was thinking of setting up an openVPN server, connecting my home 4G router and any device I want to use to access my home network to that openVPN network. Would that work?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work that way

Answer (score 1):

Renting a VPN server and then connecting your home network as well as any remote client to that one [is possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/702419/openvpn-allow-two-clients-to-connect-to-each-other-without-using-client-to-clien) as long as the VPN server is configured to allow `client-to-client` connections. However, you should be aware that the VPN server will have full access to both your home network as well as your clients so you should be able to trust that server completely.

Therefore, I would check other options before renting a VPN server:

1. Does your provider give you an IPv6 address? That way, you may be abl to use a dynDNS service that works also for IPv6
2. It may be cheaper to switch your provider and choose one that gives you an IP address rather than renting a trustworthy VPN server in addition to your cellular internet connection.

Comment: I double checked, and I don't have an IPv6 address at home. I already have a server that still has free capacity.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann In case the VPN server does not cause additional costs and does not pose a security risk, it is a good solution. Just make sure you enable the `client-to-client` option.